# Deep linking an app in PHP is not working

Tags: php, ios, deep-linking

I have a webpage that needs to check to see if an app exists using a deep link, but it doesn't seem to work like it should. I have tried the following things.

1. Using a redirect in PHP (Doesn't work)

`header('Location: exampleapp://param=test');`

2. Using a redirect using JavaScript (Doesn't work)

   ```
   var appurl = 'exampleapp://param=test';
   var appstore = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/...';

   var timeout;
   function preventPopup() {
     clearTimeout(timeout);
     timeout = null;
     window.removeEventListener('pagehide', preventPopup);
   }
   function startApp() {
       window.location = appurl;
       timeout = setTimeout(function(){
       if(confirm('You do not seem to have the App installed, do you want to go download it now?')){
           document.location = appstore;
           }
       }, 100);
       window.addEventListener('pagehide', preventPopup);
   }

   // app start is then called in the onload
   ```
3. Same as above but replace the the line `window.location = appurl;` with `document.getElementById('deeplink').click();` and adding a link in the html's webpage. (Works) `<a id="deeplink" href="exampleapp://param=test">Deep Link</a>`

Is there a reason why you can't redirect using a header in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP version doesn't work, because of the way HTTP works. The HTTP protocol doesn't specify that it should work to redirect to a different protocol from within the "Location:" header. There is nothing specific to PHP here, it's a HTTP issue.

The Javascript version doesn't work because you wanted to set the windows location. And the window cannot show the contents of "exampleapp://..." . You want the link to open like when the user clicks on it. Instead of using `window.location` you may use `document.location.href`. That should work.

Another problem:
in your code you write `exampleapp://` in 1) and 2). And in 3) you write `testapp://` - make sure you use the same URL in all three cases, so that you can be sure that the URL can work eventually..

Comment: @JasonFoster: i edited the answer.. you used two different links

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use Apples implementation called 'Smart Banners'

[image: Apple Smart Banner]

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

> You can include three comma-separated parameters in the content
>   attribute:
>
> app-id: (Required.) Your app's unique identifier. To find your app ID
>   from the iTunes Link Maker, type the name of your app in the Search
>   field, and select the appropriate country and media type. In the
>   results, find your app and select iPhone App Link in the column on the
>   right. Your app ID is the nine-digit number in between id and ?mt.
>   affiliate-data: (Optional.) Your iTunes affiliate string, if you are
>   an iTunes affiliate. If you are not, find out more about becoming an
>   iTunes affiliate at http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/.
>   app-argument: (Optional.) A URL that provides context to your native
>   app. If you include this, and the user has your app installed, she can
>   jump from your website to the corresponding position in your iOS app.
>   Typically, it is beneficial to retain navigational context because: If
>   the user is deep within the navigational hierarchy of your website,
>   you can pass the document’s entire URL, and then parse it in your app
>   to reroute her to the correct location in your app. If the user
>   performs a search on your website, you can pass the query string so
>   that she can seamlessly continue the search in your app without having
>   to retype her query. If the user is in the midst of creating content,
>   you can pass the session ID to download the web session state in your
>   app so she can nondestructively resume her work. You can generate the
>   app-argument of each page dynamically with a server-side script. You
>   can format it however you'd like, as long as it is a valid URL.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html